# Kafka consumer hangs on poll when kafka is down

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I've been playing around with a basic setup of Zookeeper and Kafka to learn how to use it, but I'm having trouble with the consumer. When Kafka is not available the call to the `poll()` method hangs until it is back online.

Kafka version: **0.10.1.0**

My code looks like this:

```
KafkaConsumer<String, byte[]> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
consumer.subscribe(topics);

while (!stopped) {
    // If by any reason Kafka is not available this call will hang
    // until Kafka is back online.
    records = consumer.poll(timeout);

    for (ConsumerRecord<String, byte[]> record : records) {
        process(record);
    }

    Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
}
```

I've read that when I call to `poll()` the consumer will try to connect to Kafka indefinitely until it is back online or until `consumer.wakeup()` is called.

I want the code act differently when Kafka is not online. **Is there any way of limiting the consumer retries or making it fail when polling from a non-existent kafka?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately this is still an issue. Many Consumer methods can hang with various scenarios.

There is a Kafka Improvement Proposal in progress, [KIP-266](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=75974886), to add timeouts to the Consumer methods to avoid hangs.

As far as I know, calling `wakeup()` from another thread is the best workaround

---

EDIT: As of Kafka 2.0.0, all Consumer calls can accept a timeout. That allows to recover control in case brokers go down.